# Reading and printing from a plain text file Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a plain text file and I am trying to recreate the 'print as written' functionality of print using the text file.

The text file currently has:

```
"""
Test1

Test1

Test1
""",
"""
Test2

Test2

Test2
""",
"""
Test3

Test4

Test5
"""
```

And my aim is to read this into a list of 3 strings, have the random module select one of those strings and end up printing it exactly as written but without the """ or ,. I can remove those characters from the file if need be, I was just guessing on how to get print to print exactly what's written as it would with:

```
print("""
Test1

Test1

Test1
""")
```

(output)

```
Test1

Test1

Test1
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I have tried:

```
import random
file = open('prebaked', 'r')
print(random.choice(file))
```

and

```
import random
with open('prebaked', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
print(random.choice(file))
```

and

```
import random
with open('prebaked', 'r') as f:
    file = list(f.read())
print(random.choice(file))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not here to write your code for you - we're here to help you with specific problems.

Comment: import random
file = open('prebaked', 'r')
print(random.choice(file))

and

import random
with open('prebaked', 'r') as f:
 file = f.read()
print(random.choice(file))

and

import random
with open('prebaked', 'r') as f:
 file = list(f.read())
print(random.choice(file))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic:

- Read the file.
- Separate strings into a list, based on `','` and remove white-spaces and `"""` from the strings.
- Call random to choose from the list.

Code:

```
import random

with open('mytextfile.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    str_list = [s.strip('\r\n\t "') for s in file_obj.read().split(',')]

print random.choice(str_list)
```

Comment: `strip('"""')` is the same as `strip('"')`, and removes any number of leading/trailing quotes.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was the easiest to get my around and I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this solution won't work correctly if any of the strings contain the character `,`.

Comment: @interjay That is also correct. There is two options here: first use `split('"""\n,\n"""')` or the other way is yours, the `literal_eval`. But in the OP's question, the file doesn't contain `','` elsewehere, but as the separator of strings.

Answer (score 2):

What your file contains is almost exactly the Python syntax for a list of strings, it's just missing the `[` and `]`. If you add these, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely evaluate the Python syntax and give you the list of strings:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
>>> literal_eval('[' + file_contents + ']')
['\nTest1\n\nTest1\n\nTest1\n', '\nTest2\n\nTest2\n\nTest2\n', '\nTest3\n\nTest4\n\nTest5\n']
```

Comment: I don't understand from that code how python knows which filename or list to read into file_contents.

Comment: @Simkill: I assumed you read the file contents into the string `file_contents`, e.g. `file_contents = my_file.read()`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I'm hazy at file I/O at best as I'm trying to teach myself Python in my spare time. Thank you for the help though, I will bear in mind that module for the future.